# Qt 3d is not installed

Tags: qt, qml

I am using windows 7 , I have Qt 5.10.1 and in Qt creator in my QMl file. when I import qt3d it does not recognize it with "Qt 3d is not installed" as an error. I don't know how to make it recognize 3d module.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qt3d-index.html

Comment: Thank you but i've aleready had a look at it. but it does not help.

Comment: Can you show your code of your .pro file and where you import the Qt 3d module?